# SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a a table called RowSettingStatus like this:

```
ReqNum    WorkID   RevNum    RowStatus
1111      10       1         NULL
1111      10       5         NULL
1111      11       2         NULL
1111      11       10        NULL
1111      106      3         NULL
1111      10       11        NULL
1111      10       12        NULL
1111      10       13        NULL
1111      10       14        NULL
1111      10       15        NULL
1111      10       16        NULL
2222      51       1         NULL
2222      51       6         NULL
2222      10       7         NULL
2222      11       2         NULL
```

My requirement is for a particular ReqNum, when WorkID = 10, the RowStatus will be updated by 'F' when RevNum is minimum and the RowStatus will be updated by 'L' when RevNum is maximum.For others it will be 'I' .

For example when I run the stored procedure with the parameter ReqNum = 1111.It will update as following at one go.

```
ReqNum    WorkID   RevNum    RowStatus

1111      10       1         F
1111      10       5         I
1111      11       2         F
1111      11       10        I
1111      106      3         F
1111      10       11        I
1111      10       12        I
1111      10       13        I
1111      10       14        I
1111      10       15        I
1111      10       16        L
2222      51       1         NULL
2222      51       6         NULL
2222      10       7         NULL
2222      11       2         NULL
```

Note: There are many rows in the table.

Please anyone can write the procedure?

Comment: Probably - have you had a go? Is this homework?

Comment: think about the case statment sir

Comment: update amounts set amount=case when ID=1 then 15 else 20 end

Comment: Why is `1111,11,2` `F` and/or why is `1111,11,10` `I` instead of `L`? Your description implied only `WorkID` `10` mattered for considering `F`-ness and `L`-ness, so I can't match your description and expected result.

Comment: Suppose for WorkId = 10, RowStatus will be F that has the min(RevNum) and RowStatus will be L that has the max(RevNum). The other RowStatus will be updated as I for that particular WorkID

Comment: @michelle - repeating your requirement doesn't address the fact that your example output doesn't match this requirement. Why are there *multiple* rows with an `F`, but only a single row with an `L`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got something *close* to your shown desired output, but as indicated in the comments, the requirements and desired output don't seem to match. I've tried to go with your written requirements, I think.

---

Sample table/data:

```
create table #RowSettingStatus (ReqNum int,WorkId int,RevNum int,RowStatus char(1))
insert into #RowSettingStatus (ReqNum,    WorkID,   RevNum,    RowStatus)
select 1111,      10,       1,         NULL union all
select 1111,      10,       5,         NULL union all
select 1111,      11,       2,         NULL union all
select 1111,      11,       10,        NULL union all
select 1111,      106,      3,         NULL union all
select 1111,      10,       11,        NULL union all
select 1111,      10,       12,        NULL union all
select 1111,      10,       13,        NULL union all
select 1111,      10,       14,        NULL union all
select 1111,      10,       15,        NULL union all
select 1111,      10,       16,        NULL union all
select 2222,      51,       1,         NULL union all
select 2222,      51,       6,         NULL union all
select 2222,      10,       7,         NULL union all
select 2222,      11,       2,         NULL
```

---

Actual update:

```
declare @ReqNum int
set @ReqNum = 1111
;with Numbered as (
    select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ReqNum,WorkID ORDER by RevNum) as rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ReqNum,WorkID ORDER by RevNum desc) as rn2
    from
        #RowSettingStatus
)
update Numbered set
    RowStatus = CASE
                   WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN 'F'
                   WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN 'L'
                   ELSE 'I'
                END
where ReqNum = @ReqNum
```

---

Results:

```
select * from #RowSettingStatus

ReqNum WorkId RevNum RowStatus
1111   10     1      F
1111   10     5      I
1111   11     2      F
1111   11     10     L --<-- This line doesn't match your output, but is the MAX(RevNum) for WorkId 11...
1111   106    3      F
1111   10     11     I
1111   10     12     I
1111   10     13     I
1111   10     14     I
1111   10     15     I
1111   10     16     L
2222   51     1      NULL
2222   51     6      NULL
2222   10     7      NULL
2222   11     2      NULL
```

I'm using [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to allow me to find the "first" and "last" rows within each `WorkId`, where the ordering means that these are, in turn, the `MIN()` and `MAX()` `RevNum` values.